# OpenGL ES clean up with Automatic Reference Counting

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, automatic-ref-counting

1. What is the correct place to call the clean up code like the following if ARC is enabled?

   ```
   if ([EAGLContext currentContext] == mContext)    
       [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil];
   ```
2. In ARC, since memory is managed by the LLVM, can we still override the dealloc method
      without any caveats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can still call this code in the `dealloc`, but depending on the structure of your code, there may be a better point for it. Perhaps `viewDidUnload`
2. You can still override `dealloc` with the following caveats:

   - You can't call `[super dealloc]`;
   - You can't call `release`, you should only do nil assignments, remove listeners and such in here.

Comment: And of course, you can/must call free() for any C-style memory you malloc()'ed, because allocation/deallocation of non-Objective-C objects (structs, C arrays, etc.) is beyond the scope of ARC.

Comment: Note that `viewDidUnload` is deprecated (and will no longer be called) in iOS 6+.  `dealloc` is probably the best place.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your first question, but for the second one : ARC forbids explicit message send of `dealloc`and `release`. You get an error when you try to call `[super dealloc]` or `[attribute release]` anywhere in your code, for example in a `dealloc`method.